qasync with IPython hangs on run_until_complete
I would like to have an asynchronous gui with PyQt5. The synchronous version of what I want would look like this:
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QMainWindow
import asyncio
import time
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        button = QPushButton("Press This")
        self.setCentralWidget(button)
        button.clicked.connect(self.function)
        self.show()
    
    def function(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        print('I have executed this')

window=MainWindow()

If I execute this in spyder for example (which is what I eventually want to do), I get a GUI, a button and a synchronous function, and the IPython console returns nicely while this is running on the background (which is what I want):
I can execute new scripts on the console while the GUI is running synchronously
However, I would like to have this method to be asynchronous, therefore I use qasync. Here is the code:
from qasync import QApplication, QEventLoop, asyncSlot, asyncClose
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QMainWindow
import asyncio
import time
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        button = QPushButton("Press This")
        self.setCentralWidget(button)
        button.clicked.connect(self.function)
        self.show()
    
    @asyncSlot()
    async def function(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print('I have executed this')
        
    @asyncClose
    async def closeEvent(self, event):
        pass

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
event_loop=QEventLoop(app)
#asyncio.set_event_loop(event_loop) SIDE NOTE: contrary to what is suggested by the qasync base examples, if I uncomment this, I get a crash of the console when I close the window with the error "got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop"

app_close_event = asyncio.Event()
app.aboutToQuit.connect(app_close_event.set)

window=MainWindow()

with event_loop:
    event_loop.run_until_complete(app_close_event.wait())

If I execute this and click on the button, I get a nice asynchronous behaviour, however the console hangs on the run_until_complete, until I close the window, which is not what I want:
the console is hanging while executing the run_until_complete
My question is therefore: How can I have an asynchronous GUI with PyQt5 that does not hang but runs in the background of the IPython console ?
I tried the nest_asyncio trick, it did not work
